# Android studio design view looks different than app run time view in emulator

Tags: android, user-interface, android-studio, android-imagebutton

I am attempting to create a calculator app which would have a similar layout to the default calculator on iOS. In the design view built into android studio, the layout of the app looks like this ([Design view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihfnN.png)) But when the app runs, it looks like this ([App view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axXH4.png)). Is their a way to fix this?

Thanks!

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.lontronix.calculator.Calculator">

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/Screen_View"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:text="@string/Filler_Text"
        android:textSize="35pt"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Clear_Button" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Equals"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/zero"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/One"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/one"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Equals"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Two_button"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/two"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Equals"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/One" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Decimal_button"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/decimal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/Equals" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/three_button"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/three"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Two_button"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/Two_button" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/equals_button"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/equals"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/Decimal_button" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Plus_Button"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/plus"
        android:layout_above="@+id/equals_button"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/Decimal_button" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Four_Button"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/four"
        android:layout_above="@+id/One"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Five_Button"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/five"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Two_button"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/Four_Button" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Six_Button"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/six"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Eight_Button"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/Two_button" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Minus_Button"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/minus"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Six_Button"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/three_button" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Seven_Button"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/seven"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Four_Button"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Eight_Button"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/eight"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Seven_Button"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/Seven_Button" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Nine_Button"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/nine"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Six_Button"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/Five_Button" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Multiply_Button"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/multiply"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Minus_Button"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/Nine_Button" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Clear_Button"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/clear"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Seven_Button"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Plus_Minus_Button"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/plus_minus"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Screen_View"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/Clear_Button" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Percent_Button"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/percent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Screen_View"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/Eight_Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The layout does scale slightly based on the screen size. You cannot avoid there being differences between different screens. Change the size of the design window and you will see that it changes based on the size of the screen¨å

Comment: @LunarWatcher Last night when I worked on the UI, I designed  it using a pixel (5 inch screen), and I still have the UI set to be 5 inches.

Comment: Is the **design view** also set to 5 inches? And is the emulator also 5 inches?

Comment: @LunarWatcher Yes, both are set as a pixel with a 5 inch screen.

Comment: It's not a good idea generally to give your views absolute sizes.  You have five rows of buttons, how about giving them each 20% of the height?

Comment: @nasch what would be the best way to do that?

Comment: A `TableLayout` would probably work well, or a series of horizontal `LinearLayout`s.